# Destructing assignment with dots in property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
const myObject = { 'docs.count': 1000, uuid: 11244, 'pri.store.size': 2453 }
```

I would like to do a destructuring assignment. Is that only possible for this type of fields?

```
const { uuid } = myObject;
```

Thanks!

Comment: While this may seem like an annoying question, why would you want this? And how would you reference a variable with a dot in it later, if it were possible?

Comment: Its useful to take only what you need out of an object and if the object has this kind of property names, I would like to know the limitations of the destructuring assignment.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I understood that you wanted to do the same shorthand destruct for the dotted property. Seems I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Variable names can't include a dot, so you can't get do `const docs.count = 1000`, for example. Destructuring allows you to extract the values even if the property name can't be a the name of a variable, but you'll need to [assign them a valid variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names):

```js
const myObject = { 'docs.count': 1000, uuid: 11244, 'pri.store.size': 2453 }

const { 'docs.count': docsCount } = myObject;

console.log(docsCount);
```

Comment: Technically global variables can contain a dot: window["foo.bar"]=5;

Comment: They are properties of the `window` object. You can't call them as a standard variable `console.log(foo.bar);`, only as a property of the window object `console.log(window["foo.bar"])`.